# What does this number means, in the "low quality posts" page?

Tags: support, review-page

What does the number I see to the left of "show full question," or "show full answer" links mean?

[image: meta.drupal.SE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All posts start out at 100, and then a heuristic calculates the score.  Only posts with a score <80 will appear on the /review page.

See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75929/140548) for more details.